# Software to detect column relationships in a table?

Tags: database

Consider the following scenario:

There are two columns in a table, ACCT_STA_CD (Account Status Code) and ACCT_CLSD_DT (Account Closed Date).  In ACCT_STA_CD, the value of 'A' means 'Active'.  Since the account is active, there should be no corresponding value for ACCT_CLSD_DT, but for some reason there is.  That is a data quality issue which requires the application of a rule/constraint for both columns.

Here's my question: is there any kind of software tool that can do this sort of relationship detection?  Something that would tell me that the presence of a value in column a is dependent on a value in column b, or vice versa, but where the columns do not necessarily have a key relationship.

Comment: Welcome njrob! If I understand your question correctly, an advanced spreadsheet tool (such as OpenOffice Calc, LibreOffice Calc, or Microsoft Excel) *might* do what you need.  You can program a 3rd column that detects an 'A' in ACCT_STA_CD and the presence of any value in ACCT_CLSD_DT in the same row.  The 3rd column can then display a flag, alerting you to the data quality issue.  Would that help you?

Comment: "`There are two columns in a table`" - what kind of table? Are you speaking of a database? If so, which one?